# LWC1503: Parsing error: Leading decorators must be attached to a class declaration

Tags: lightning-web-components

my code is below as I declared (track) in the class still I am getting the error.

```
import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';

export default class HelloWorld extends LightningElement {}
@track greeting ='World';
changeHandler(event)
{
    this.greeting=event.target.value;
}
```

Comment: Your editor probably added `LightningElement {}` but you need to move the last `}` to the end of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code must be written inside the body of the class; if you read carefully the error message indicates the same.

Mostly constants can be declared before the class and after imports:

```
import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';

export default class HelloWorld extends LightningElement {
    @track greeting ='World';
    changeHandler(event) {
        this.greeting=event.target.value;
    }
}
```