# LWC not displaying any Data in component when attempting to display the Account on Contact

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to display an LWC component on my contact that shows the Account Page, but I see no data when the page is loaded. (I'm using standard objects as a proxy here as the end goal is to use this for custom objects)

Any thoughts on why this is happening and suggestions to fix it??

Here's what I see:
[image]

Here's the HTML for the Component:

```
  <lightning-card title="Account Information" icon-name="standard:account">
    <template if:true={contact.data}>
      <lightning-record-form
        record-id={contact.data.fields.AccountId.value}
        object-api-name="Account"
        layout-type="Full"
        mode="readonly"
      >
      </lightning-record-form>
    </template>
    <template if:true={error}>
      <div class="slds-text-color_error">
        <p>{error}</p>
      </div>
    </template>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Here's the Javascript for the Component (the Account ID is correctly shown when I open the Console logs):

```
import { getRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import CONTACT_ACCOUNTID_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.AccountId";

export default class AccountDisplay extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId; // Contact record Id
  error;

  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: [CONTACT_ACCOUNTID_FIELD] })
  contact({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
      console.log("Account Id:", data.fields.AccountId.value);
      this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
      console.error("Error:", JSON.stringify(error));
      this.error = "Error fetching account information";
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the XML for the Component:

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>53.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <objects>
                <object>Contact</object>
            </objects>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code.I hope it would work
Please Update your markUp with the below code

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Account Information" icon-name="standard:account">
        <template if:true={AccountCheck}>
          <lightning-record-form
            record-id={AccountID}
            object-api-name="Account"
            layout-type="Full"
            mode="readonly"
          >
          </lightning-record-form>
        </template>
        <template if:true={error}>
          <div class="slds-text-color_error">
            <p>{errorMessage}</p>
          </div>
        </template>
      </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Please Update your JS file with the below code

```
@api recordId; // Contact record Id
errorMessage;
error;
AccountID;

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: [CONTACT_ACCOUNTID_FIELD] })
contact({ error, data }) {
  if (data) {
    if(data.fields.AccountId.value)
    {
        this.AccountID = data.fields.AccountId.value;
        this.error = false;
    }
    else{ //if Contact don't have AccountId
       this.error = true;
       this.errorMessage = "Account not found ";
    } 
  } else if (error) {
    console.error("Error:", JSON.stringify(error));
    this.error = true;
    this.errorMessage = "Error fetching account information";
    
  }
}
get AccountCheck()
{
    if(this.AccountID)
    {
        return true ;
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: I get an error that says "LWC1503: Parsing error: Leading decorators must be attached to a class declaration. (1:5) (1:5)"

Comment: Hi @CoryO.Bennett Please refer to the below link,same Query addressed. (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301342/lwc1503-parsing-error-leading-decorators-must-be-attached-to-a-class-declarati)